# Как сверстать подобный блок?

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

Подскажите как можно реализовать верстку с таким фоном желательно респонсив. Поделитесь мыслями. Красными линиями показана ширина блока container. 
[image: блок]

Comment: ??? фоновый рисунок ставьте в тело, Контейнер - позиционируйте в центре. Вопрос в чем???

Comment: При использовании данного метода при разных размерах экрана. фон будет уезжать. Нужно чтобы ромбы и круги оставались на линии.

Comment: @zombie  а вы что сверстали уже ? это не бесплатная биржа где делают что то за вас